# forward and backward error

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

Hello I am a bit confused on the forward and backward error for floating point computation inaccuracy. Let s take only the absolute values. I understand that the forward error  is the difference between the result and the solution. The backward error is smallest Δx such that f (x + Δx) = y*; in other words, the backward error tells us what problem the algorithm actually solved (per wikipedia). By researching also I read that the Backward error is more stable. Does this also apply when I search the absolute value? Because only thing I could find was for the relative error. However how am I supposed to choose between choosing forward or backward error for numerical purposes for absolute values?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the backward error for absolute values."  Absolute value of what?  Can you give a formula that shows what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello thank you for replying. Basically I want to  solve a system of
non-linear equations with Newton’s method. Starting from an initial guess x(0) i want to estimate the solution and I have 2 stopping criteria. The absolute value of the forward error ( || estimate - solution of my system||) or the absolute value of the backward error( || X_k + (T/N) * F(X_k+1) -X_k+1||) I used forward euler to calculate X_k+1 as my starting estimate

Comment: As it is currently written your question is very general and it is hard to pinpoint your *exact* problem. In particular the numbers $T$ and $N$ introduced in you last comment are not undefined. It is clear, that you are solving a differential equation using an implicit method which requires the solution of a nonlinear equation. Is the main issue the criteria used to determine when Newton's method has converged? You should name the differential equation and the method use to integrate it.